# GeoLocation Plugin get Latitude and Longitude is not working on offline Mode android version mobile version 6, 9

Tags: ionic4

I am  using ionic v4 using get current lat and long using geolocation plugin but it working properly on online when offline mode some of android version mobiles not working ex version  android redmin version 9 and motog version 6 and redmi version 8 please helps us we in order to solve this problem

Comment: Welcome to SO. To get good answers, please review: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example
When asking a question, people will be better able to provide help if you provide code that they can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem. This is called creating a minimal, reproducible example (reprex), a minimal, complete and verifiable example (mcve), or a minimal, workable example (mwe). - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: This is a very specific question. I don't know the answer but I do know that in the past I've read about background tasks being killed in underpowered cheap devices. The good news is that what I read was that they figured out a way to give it more priority. The bad news is I have no idea where I read it.